# How to perform Exception Handling while building Connector Using Devkit in Anypoint Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I am fairly new in Building Custom Connector using Devkit in Anypoint Studio. I was able to write a simple connector connector which can connect to the external API . 
Now i want to add basic exception handling to it for handling things like connection failure , resource not available , failed authentication etc

Please guide how can i acheive this .

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Danish

Answer (score 1):

You can always use ordinary java try catch statement but there is also another alternative @OnException with this annotation you can define generic exception handlers to your code. 
You can read more about it [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-connector-devkit/v/3.7/annotation-reference#onexceptionan)

best regards 
Jack